# waf: Uselib options in custom rule

Tags: build, build-automation, waf

I have a waf build script and need to invoke a program which is not officially supported.

```py
#file wscript
def configure(conf):
  conf.env.LIB = ['c', 'd']
  conf.env.INCLUDES = ['include']
  conf.env.LIB_xml2 = ['xml2']
  conf.env.INCLUDES_xml2 = ['/usr/include/libxml2']

def build(bld):
  bld(rule="dstep ${SRC} -o ${TGT} ${LIB_ST:LIB} ${DINC_ST:INCLUDES}",
    use="xml2",
    source="header.h",
    target="target.d",
    )
```

This expands to `dstep header.h -o target.d -lc -ld -I/usr/include/libxml2`, so only the global LIB variable works, the use parameter seems to entirely ignored.

How can I make it respect the use parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For waf to process the `use` keyword, you must add the `use` feature to your task generator. You also need to add a "compile" aware feature like c, d or cxx. Like this:

```py
def build(bld):
  bld(
    rule="dstep ${SRC} -o ${TGT} ${LIB_ST:LIB} ${DINC_ST:INCLUDES}",
    features = ["use", "c"],
    use="xml2",
    source="header.h",
    target="target.d",
  )
```

You can also program specifics for your dstep (You have to define a `dstep` feature and define the `USELIB_VARS["dstep"]`)

Note: See `ccroot.py` in waf code.

Comment: Doesn't work. Same for ```features = ['use', 'uselib']```

Comment: You should probably use a compiling feature like c, d, cxx. I will try to make it work tomorrow if I have time :)

Comment: Using the feautre 'c' did the job. Thank you. Update your answer and I'll confirm it

Comment: Glad I help. waf is great tool I use for years.